# What's the name of the design technique where you make something clearer by using contrast?

Tags: design-patterns, design-theory

For instance, choosing a background color that makes all text stand out better, or giving all hyperlinks a background color the opposite of the color of the actual hyperlinks. An example of this is [my HappyUser proposal](http://happyuser.handcraft.com) where the page's background color is a shade of green that makes the blue hyperlinks stand out better than if the background color were white.

I'm sure there's a name for this technique, but I have no idea. Anyone know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd just call it using contrast in a usable way. Make sure you also make it usable for people who can't perceive color!

Comment: Exactly, as a great designer Andy Rutledge says, contarast is the most fundamental element of meaning: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/contrastandmeaning - and in my opinion, working with contrast is not 'special technique', you would hardly be a designer without using it...

Comment: It's interesting, because this is what I've always called it, but I felt like (not having a trained design background) I wasn't using the proper name for it. But it looks like there isn't a name for it, after all.

Answer (score 6):

... also, sorry for thread hijacking, but I think it would be worth mentioning the [gestalt principles](http://graphicdesign.spokanefalls.edu/tutorials/process/gestaltprinciples/gestaltprinc.htm) and Andy Rutledge's excellent series of articles about using it to make the visuals more 'navigatable':

- [Gestalt Principles of Perception 1: Figure Ground Relationships](http://www.andyrutledge.com/gestalt-principles-1-figure-ground-relationship.php)
- [Gestalt Principles of Perception 2: Similarity](http://www.andyrutledge.com/gestalt-principles-2-similarity.php)
- [Gestalt Principles of Perception 3: Proximity, Uniform Connectedness, and Good Continuation](http://www.andyrutledge.com/gestalt-principles-3.php)
- [Gestalt Principles of Perception 4: Common Fate](http://www.andyrutledge.com/common-fate.php)
- [Gestalt Principles of Perception 5: Closure](http://www.andyrutledge.com/closure.php)

Comment: Fantastic links! Too bad they're not about contrast, but I kind of want to accept this as the best answer...

Comment: The gestalt of similarity covers contrast "things that are similar are perceived to be more related than things that are dissimilar"

Answer (score 3):

Contrast? Complementary colors?
Not sure if it's really a "technique", though. More a design approach.

Answer (score 2):

In the study of art it is called **Chiaroscuro**

[link text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiaroscuro)

Comment: Chiaroscuro doesn't seem to fit here. More of a painting style to achieve dramatic effect. Like Rembrandt paintings. Still high contrast but a wide range of tones. Complementary colors definitely come to mind like Max stated, but that is about the colors opposite each other on a color wheel. Not sure what opposing contrasts would be. The biggest opposing contrast is black and white :)

Answer (score 1):

There are design principles called Proximity, Alignment, Repetition and **Contrast**. See [The Non-Designers Design Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321534042) by Robin William (recommendable).

She uses the term contrast in a large sense: not only contrasting colors, but also contrasting font sizes, font families etc ("different things should look different".)